# MySQL configurations are not saved after restarting windows server machine

Tags: mysql, iis-7, configuration

I have a PHP application hosted on a windows server 2008 R2 machine.

I had a problem with strict mode in MySQL and solved it by disabling the strict mode using the following command

```
set GLOBAL.sql_mode='';
```

When I restart the machine, strict mode is enabled again and the problem exists again.

How can I solve this issue ?

**Edit:**

In addition to @Jérémy Munoz's answer, you have to restart the MySQL service using the following commands:

```
net stop MySQL
```

then

```
net start MySQL
```

Comment: By reading the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this : `sql-mode="what you want"` below `[mysqld]` in the **my.cnf** configuration file.

Comment: That worked for me, I was adding it under [mysql]
But what is the difference ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Write the command into the MySQL Server config file.

Comment: Of course I tried this approach, I wrote sql-mode="" but did not work.
Still losing changes after restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It happened that there were several my.cnf files in system. One in /etc/mtsql and other in /usr/. And latter had bad parameters.